# crosstab() query shifting columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, crosstab

I am using a crosstab function in postgres. Basic SQL is:

```
select distinct  
       o_location,
       co_name,
       o_date,
       o_ndate,
       o_day,
       o_hour,
       o_type
  from outputs_txt
  left join courses on o_course = co_foreign
  left join locations on o_location = l_code
 where o_date = '2011-10-10' 
 order by o_hour
```

My crosstab query is

```
SELECT *
  FROM crosstab(
'SELECT DISTINCT
        COALESCE(o_location, '''')
       ,o_hour AS hour
       ,c.co_name
   FROM outputs_txt AS d
   LEFT JOIN courses AS c 
     on o_course = c.co_foreign
   LEFT JOIN locations as a 
     on o_location = a.l_code
  WHERE d.o_date = ''2011-10-10'''
)
AS ct(
 o_location varchar
,hour_0  varchar
,hour_1  varchar
,hour_2  varchar
,hour_3  varchar
,hour_4  varchar
,hour_5  varchar
,hour_6  varchar
,hour_7  varchar
,hour_8  varchar
,hour_9  varchar
,hour_10 varchar
,hour_11 varchar
,hour_12 varchar
,hour_13 varchar
,hour_14 varchar
,hour_15 varchar
,hour_16 varchar
,hour_17 varchar)
```

The problem is that results are all shifted left.
For example, if a course in one location should be shown on `hour_8` it is shown in `hour_0`.
That is for all courses in all locations. They are all aligned left.

Where am I going it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

As there are no sample data, I can only guess. Here is what strikes me:
There is no **`ORDER BY`** in your crosstab function. I added one:

```
SELECT *
  FROM crosstab(
'SELECT DISTINCT
        COALESCE(o_location, '''')
       ,o_hour AS hour
       ,c.co_name
   FROM outputs_txt AS d
   LEFT JOIN courses AS c    ON o_course = c.co_foreign
   LEFT JOIN locations as a  ON o_location = a.l_code
  WHERE d.o_date = ''2011-10-10''
  ORDER BY 1,2'
)
AS ct(
 o_location varchar
,hour_0  varchar
,hour_1  varchar
,hour_2  varchar
,hour_3  varchar
,hour_4  varchar
,hour_5  varchar
,hour_6  varchar
,hour_7  varchar
,hour_8  varchar
,hour_9  varchar
,hour_10 varchar
,hour_11 varchar
,hour_12 varchar
,hour_13 varchar
,hour_14 varchar
,hour_15 varchar
,hour_16 varchar
,hour_17 varchar)
```

If you want `hour_0` first you have to order by `o_hour`. I quote the [manual on crosstab functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tablefunc.html):

> In practice the SQL query should always specify ORDER BY 1,2 to ensure
>   that the input rows are properly ordered, that is, values with the
>   same row_name are brought together and correctly ordered within the
>   row.

Comment: order by doesn't seems to have any effect.

Comment: order by doesn't seems to have any effect.
i get 
o_location hour_0 hour_1 hour_2 hour_3 hour_4 ...... hour_17....
11  sub1 sub1 sub1 sub2 sub3 ''
22  subX subX subY subY '' ''

when I should get smth like
o_location hour_0 hour_1 hour_2 hour_3 hour_4 hour_5 hour_6 ...... hour_17....
11   sub1 sub1 sub1  sub2 sub3
22  subX subX    subY subY subY

Comment: @Yebach: please edit your question with proper format. That's too hard to decipher.